# Google Analytics session management for same app in different tabs, in a react app

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

Here's an example flow:

Referrer -> My App (1) -> Email is sent -> User clicks on email link -> My App (2)

I'm using `react-ga`. Step 1 is a session that contains `Referrer URL` (outside site that links to mine). Step 2 comes from an email, `react-ga` is initialized again and I assume a new session starts, in a new tab -- Referrer URL is lost in GA's reports. Step 1 and 2 are part of the same flow, so what is a good practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

No responses, so if anybody encounters the same, here's what I decided to do:

1. Set up Google Goal
2. Get `sessionId` from `GA`, pass it when doing `GA.initialize()` at (2)
3. Link sessions with `userId`, GA calls it session unification or something in that spirit
4. Extend expiration time of session cookie  (default is I think 30 mins)